# Why does the Android App that sends data to azure SQL Database not running on phone but on AVD on Android Studio?

Tags: android, apk, azure-sql-database

I am trying to make an ANDROID APP that sends data from phone to the SQL Database at the Azure Cloud.

I have followed, as close as possible,the tutorials given on
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-android-get-started/

First Off All, I have a little bit confusion Regarding creating an .APK file in android studio.
Here, I have assumed my .apk is in \app\build\outputs.

Now, I am trying to run app-debug.apk on my REDMI 1s Android Version 4.3 JLS36C, the app simply opens and Vanishes away. I Also tried to run it on Samsung Galaxy Note-3 Neo (SM-N750) Android Version:Android 4.4.2

When I try to run the app on the emulator itself, it is running. But not on Phones. What to do? Here is my build.gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.zumoappname"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'aars'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2'
compile (group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-notifications-handler', version: '1.0.1', ext: 'jar')
}
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting breakpoints in the **onCreate** method and step through the code so you can find out where the code is failing.

Another issue I have run into is device failures when a network connection is not actually available.

But definitely try to find out what line of code is failing...

Comment: How to Set those Breakpoints? I am new to the App Making. Please help